# Separate Check all that apply responses

Tags: r

I have some check all that apply responses from google forms that doesn't use any kind of delimiter to separate out responses. I'm trying to use str_extract with the code below to separate each response into their respective columns but I keep just getting NA in the new column

```
test$learnAAA<-str_extract(test$learn,"Affective Statements (expressions of feelings in response to specific behaviors of others)")
```

I'm using code that I've used in the past and it worked for this same type of issues so I'm not sure what the issue is now.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e .`dput(head(test$learn, 10))`

Comment: You have some metacharacters `()`.  It can be either escaped `\\(` or wrap with `fixed` i.e. `test$learnAAA<-str_extract(test$learn, fixed("Affective Statements (expressions of feelings in response to specific behaviors of others)"))`. Without a reproducible example, it is just a guess